# AddChildViewController issue while adding UITableViewController having UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have this code:

```
navtablecontroller = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
navtablecontroller.tableView.delegate = self;
navtablecontroller.tableView.dataSource = self;

CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 83.0;
frame.size.height = 200.0;
navtablecontroller.view.frame = frame;

navtablecontroller.title = @"mynameasdasd";
[self addChildViewController:navtablecontroller];
[self.view addSubview:navtablecontroller.view];
[navtablecontroller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This perfectly creates a UITableView on the screen exactly as the frame mentioned.

Now I try to add a UINavigationController and have this UITableViewController as its RootViewController.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navtablecontroller];
nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

And then to add this as my childViewController I do:

```
[self addChildViewController:nav];
[self.view addSubview:nav.view];
[nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Unfortunately instead of creating a UINavigationController in the small frame mentioned in the code, the entire screen is replaced by the UINavigationController.

I just need that small frame to have the UINavigationController with the UITableView as its rootviewcontroller and not the entire screen. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. One has to set the frame of the UINavigationController to the frame of the UITableViewController.

```
nav.view.frame = frame;
```

Where frame is the frame of the UITableViewController.